# Postgres SQL | IF ELSE | HOW TO

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am using psql (PostgreSQL) 11.2 (Debian 11.2-1.pgdg90+1).
I am trying to write a logic in .PSQL file that needs to import some data into a table if this table is empty, else do something else.

I am struggling to find the correct syntax to make it work.
Would appreciate some help around this.

```
    DO $$ BEGIN
    SELECT count(*) from (SELECT 1 table_x LIMIT 1) as isTableEmpty
    IF isTableEmpty > 0
    THEN
            INSERT INTO table_x
            SELECT * FROM table_b;
    ELSE
            INSERT INTO table_y
            SELECT * FROM table_b;    
    END IF;
    END $$;
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Read [plpgsql structure](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-structure.html).  Then you would know you need a `DECLARE` section to declare `isTableEmpty`  and from here [Select into](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW) that you need to `select into`  the `isTableEmpty` variable. So:

```
...
DECLARE
   isTableEmpty integer;
BEGIN
   SELECT count(*) into isTableEmpty from (SELECT 1 table_x LIMIT 1);
...
```

Though I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish with?:

```
SELECT count(*) from (SELECT 1 table_x LIMIT 1) as isTableEmpty
```

As that is always going to return 1.

Answer (score 0):

You are using count just to determine that a row exists or not in the table. To do so you need to create a variable in the DO block, select into that variable, and reference that variable. This is all unnecessary; you can just use `exists(...)` instead of `count(*) ...`. See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=5d6dcf5d7382d294e6f21b682fa7cfb9);

```
do $$ 
begin
    
    if not exists (select null from table_x) then 
       insert into table_x (...) 
            values (...);
    else
       insert into table_y (...) 
            values (...);   
    end if;
end ; 
$$;
```